# How to make the hovering trigger an animation only on a circle area in a div with radius border with jquery

Tags: jquery, animation, hover, geometry

I am not a programmer, and I am trying my best to solve the situation but after several hours and headache I give up and I am asking for help.

I have a circular logo (a div with enough radius px to become a circle and some text in it), and I have an animation that come out from behind the logo when I hover on it.

I noticed that my animation it triggers on the "empty area" between the circular logo and the div that hold the logo (that it is still a square). 
At the moment my script it is this:

```
$("#logo").hover(function(event){     // Hovering
    myHover = "transition";
    $("#black").stop().animate({"top":"-200px"}, speed/2, function(){
        myHover = 1;
    });
},function(event){      // Finish hovering
    myHover = "transition";
    $("#black").stop().animate({"top":"0px"}, speed/2, function(){
        myHover = 0;
    });
});
```

I tried looking on the web and on stack overflow to find something that will help me, and the nearest thing that I found it is this:

http://jsbin.com/oqewo - from this other question [Accurately detect mouseover event for a div with rounded corners](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2006419/accurately-detect-mouseover-event-for-a-div-with-rounded-corners)

I tried to implement it and I did come out with something that it is not smooth enough as animation (I tried to debug trying to move back and forward with the mouse on the logo to see the reaction of the script):

```
$(".myCircle").hover(
    // when the mouse enters the box do...
    function(){
        var $box = $(this),
        offset = $box.offset(),
        radius = $box.width() / 2,
        circle = new SimpleCircle(offset.left + radius, offset.top + radius, radius);

        $box.mousemove(function(e){
            if(circle.includesXY(e.pageX, e.pageY) && myHover != "transition"){
                $(this).css({"cursor":"pointer"});
                myHover = "transition";
                $("#black").stop().animate({"top":"-200px"}, speed/2, function(){
                    myHover = 1;
                });
            }else if(!circle.includesXY(e.pageX, e.pageY)){
                $(this).css({"cursor":"default"});
                myHover = "transition";
                $("#black").animate({"top":"0px"}, speed/2, function(){
                    myHover = 0;
                });
            }
       });

    },
    // when the mouse leaves the box do...
    function() {       
        //alert("in")
       //$(this).includesXY(e.pageX, e.pageY)
        myHover = "transition";
        $(this).css({"cursor":"default"});
        $("#black").stop().animate({"top":"0px"}, speed/2, function(){
            myHover = 0;
        });
    }
)
```

I inserted a variable myHover = 0; at the start of my functions because I needed a variable that would let me know when the animation is completed, it is hidden behind the logo, or in transition.

And I don't know WHEN and HOW to use the .unbind property so I will not suck enough cpu.
Is there anything better than mouseenter event? It triggers various time, and only when I move the mouse on the logo, and not when I have the mouse on the logo during the animation. Anyway any suggestion or revision of any kind on approach this problem it is more than welcome :)

==========================

**UPDATE**

I might find a way, it seems to work, but I am not sure if it is possible to optimise/clean it, or if I am using unbind properly, someone can check my code?

```
$(".myCircle").hover(
        // when the mouse enters the box do...
        function(){
            var $box = $(this),
            offset = $box.offset(),
            radius = $box.width() / 2,
            circle = new SimpleCircle(offset.left + radius, offset.top + radius, radius);

            $box.mousemove(function(e){
            if(circle.includesXY(e.pageX, e.pageY) && myHover != "transition1"){
                $(this).css({"cursor":"pointer"});
                myHover = "transition1";
                $("#black").stop().animate({"top":"-200px"}, speed/2, function(){
                    myHover = 1;
                });
            }

            else if(!circle.includesXY(e.pageX, e.pageY)){
                $(this).css({"cursor":"default"});
                if(myHover == 1 || myHover == "transition1"){
                    myHover = "transition0";
                    $("#black").stop().animate({"top":"0px"}, speed/2, function(){
                        myHover = 0;
                    });
                }
            }
       });

    },
    // when the mouse leaves the box do...
    function() {       
        if(myHover == 1 || myHover == "transition1"){
            myHover = "transition0";
            $(this).css({"cursor":"default"});
            $("#black").stop().animate({"top":"0px"}, speed/2, function(){
                myHover = 0;
            })
        };
        $("#container").unbind('mousemove');
    }
)
```

The `SimpleCircle` class used within this code, from the demo mentioned above, is defined as:

```
function SimpleCircle(x, y, r) {
  this.centerX = x;
  this.centerY = y;
  this.radius = r;
}

SimpleCircle.prototype = {
  distanceTo: function(pageX, pageY) {
    return Math.sqrt(Math.pow(pageX - this.centerX, 2) + Math.pow(pageY - this.centerY, 2));
  },
  includesXY: function(x, y) {
    return this.distanceTo(x, y) <= this.radius;
  }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With regard to your update, it all looks good.

You may get a slight performance upgrade by reversing the order of the two `if()` parameters so that `myHover != "transition1"` is first.  The `&&` is short-circuit, so if `myHover != "transition1"` is false, the expensive circle inclusion check does not need to be called.

Also on the `else if()` might be worth having some variable set to something that says you have already set the cursor to stop that getting called continuously.

Looking at the `SimpleCircle` class, the only expensive operations it makes are two power calls and a square root (`Math.pow() x 2 + Math.sqrt()`).  Whether or not it is worth trying to get that any faster is debatable, only optimisation I can think of there is to check if the coordinates are within the square within the circle which is four quick comparisons, this covers 50% of the interior points, but obviously slows down the other 50% of points.  To see if it improved matters you would have to test it.

[image: Square inside a circle inside a square]

Comment: Thx for the answer! I am looking for "SimpleCircle" + jquery on google but I am not finding anything, where should I look?

Comment: @Littlemad I have added the `SimpleCircle` class to your question from the example you were reading; so that the question is more complete for those that look at it.

Comment: So the simpleCircle class is "(Math.pow() x 2 + Math.sqrt())" am I right?

Comment: No... that was my analysis of the performance of the routine you are using from it.  The code is in your question now, I added it for you.

Comment: The `SimpleCircle` class is a bit of code that provides a method called `includesXY(x,y)` that tells you if a given point is within the circle.  In order to determine this it has to do some very basic geometry (pythagoras), which uses those mathematical operations.  The square root is not the most optimal of operations to perform, powers are just being using for squared so could be replaced with multiplies, but you might get better performance by checking if in the "inner square" of the circle first, before having to make the calculation.  See diagram.  If you need help with the maths, shout.