# Round mask on an image growing from centre of that image

Tags: javascript, jquery

On a click of some button I need to show an image of a vinyl record. The image will appear somewhere next to the button and is a transparent png to make it look round.
The problem is it needs to be shown using a circle mask animating from a dot in the centre of the image and expanding to show the whole "record". How to create a rounded animated mask that will reveal the "record" image without zooming/rescaling the image.

Does anyone know a JavaScript or preferably jQuery library capable of something like that?

If you know of such a thing in a different language it might help me to write something of my own.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you could create a large white (or background-colored) PNG with an alpha transparency hole in the center. Place this on top of the image to be revealed, then scale it up while keeping it pinned at its center point. Once it's scaled to the point where the entire underlying image is within the transparent hole, remove the covering image.

I have no idea how this would perform (probably badly!), but it's a thought.

Comment: Hmmm that's a thought, I'll have to try it. Thanks.

Comment: Just came back to this question. @KenRedler - it performed really badly so in the end we changed the logic of the whole effect.

Comment: Well, it was a bit of a crazy idea, but now we know for sure.

Answer (score 1):

HTML comes in rectangles as a rule, if you have an image with transparency, then you can scale it, keeping it's centre constant.

If you need it to be selectable only within the circle, then you will need to check the mouse coordinate for click operations to see if it is within the circle, within it's containing rectangle.  See: [How to make the hovering trigger an animation only on a circle area in a div with radius border with jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4293925/how-to-make-the-hovering-trigger-an-animation-only-on-a-circle-area-in-a-div-with)

---

@6bytes suggested using rounded corners.

Chrome and FireFox currently surround round-corners via the `border-radius` and `-moz-border-radius` CSS attributes, so you can achieve a circle visually with `50%` border radius.  However, this is only a visual difference on an underlying rectangle, clicks within the rectangle still count as being on the circle itself.

```
#circle {
    -moz-border-radius: 50%;
    border-radius: 50%;
}
```

Basic Rectangle Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/rL4BU/2/

You can put some code in to check if clicks are within the circle to fix this.

Circle Clicks Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/rL4BU/4/

Comment: What about a rectangle with big enough rounded corners?

Comment: @6bytes: The only way of getting rounded corners in HTML is with the `border-radius` CSS attribute, IE9 will support this, but lower versions do not.  Chrome and FireFox support it (older FireFox support `-moz-border-radius` instead, latter both).  But it does not help click events, see this demo: http://jsfiddle.net/rL4BU/1/

Comment: I think you misunderstood me. I click somewhere (I don't care what and where) and the animation to show the rounded image should appear on the page. I edited the question to make my problem more clear. The animation is a problem, not the button.

Comment: @6bytes: How about this, this is using the rounded rectangle rather than a backing image, but the principle is the same on the animation: http://jsfiddle.net/rL4BU/5/