# Is it possible to make small circles via CSS?

Tags: css, geometry

Rather than using images, I was wondering if anyone knows how to make small circles with outlines using CSS.

I'm trying to make something similar to the bullseye symbol or Target logo.

Comment: Which HTML/CSS standard are you targetting?  This is fairly straight-forward using the `canvas` tag.  (IIRC, Adobe Illustrator will export to a format that can be embedded on a page).

Comment: I think my answer here is exactly what you're looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4840736/easier-way-to-create-circle-div-than-using-an-image/4844059#4844059 - if not, let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at this library:
http://jsdraw2d.jsfiction.com/

For drawing circles there are examples in http://jsdraw2d.jsfiction.com/demo/circleellipse.htm

Comment: The resources linked in this answer seem to be dead by now.

Answer (score 14):

You can use div's with rounded corners.

```
<style>
.circle{
    -webkit-border-radius:8px;
    -moz-border-radius:8px;
    border-radius:8px;
    border:1px solid #ccc;
    width:8px;
    height:8px;
}
</style>
<div class="circle"></div>
```

But, may be, it's better to use canvas and JavaScript.

Answer (score 8):

For anyone else who wants to draw a small circle, the following code makes use of scale to resize the circle. Just chamge the scale values and you're good to go!

```
.circle{
    border: 2px solid #1111a1;
    padding: 10px 40px; 
    background: #dddddd;
    width: 1px;
    height: 60px;
    border-radius: 100px;
    transform: scale(0.5, 0.5);
}
```

[Plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/04N38lykaxbZC7kDgwjQ?p=preview)

Answer (score 6):

Not sure I really understood your question, but this is how you draw a circle with CSS :

```
.circle
{
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;

    display: block;
    border: 1px solid black;

    border-radius: 100px;
}
```