# Creating circles in css support in IE versions

Tags: css, cross-browser, geometry

I have to create a circle in css without images.Using border-radius we can get in the Firefox,chrome and Opera browsers.IE does not support the border-radius property.Can any one provide me link or a way to create the circle in css for IE version browsers .I had seen the [Raphel](http://raphaeljs.com/)

Other than this library,If any jquery plugin is there provide me link.

Answer (score 1):

download [pie.htc](http://css3pie.com/) for support in IE. It's a better way to work with css3 property for IE.

check this example.

[Easier way to create circle div than using an image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4840736/easier-way-to-create-circle-div-than-using-an-image)

[How to use CSS to surround a number with a circle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4861224/how-to-css-a-number-to-be-surrounded-by-a-circle)

Answer (score 1):

jsDraw2D : 2D Graphics Library for JavaScript

http://jsdraw2d.jsfiction.com/demo/circleellipse.htm