# Solid ball of specific size and position

Tags: jquery, html, css, image

How would you guys make a solid ball of specific size and position so that the size or the position will not change according to its outer element. ( in the major browsers )

Lets say the outer element would be another ball that is always white.

Of course number one might be to use image of a solid ball.. depending on the case but, what about if i wanted the inner ball color to be easily editable.

So: How to achieve editable ball of specific size and position so that either one wont change on any major browser? ( considering that shape should also stay intact in all major browsers )

Only editable factor would have to be the color of it.

Comment: In cases like this you use absolute or fixed positioning of elements in css and do not place one element inside of other one.

Comment: @eugeneK its more about the whole scenario. But, you are right about that part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

may be can use `border-radius` to make the div a circle.  So it can be easy for you to edit the color of div. For position you can define `position absolute or fixed` to it.

**FOR EXAMPLE**

```
div{
    -webkit-border-radius: 999px;
        -moz-border-radius: 999px;
        border-radius: 999px;
        behavior: url(PIE.htc);
    position:absolute;
    top:20px;
    right:50px;
    width:200px;
   height:200px;
}
```

check this examples.

[Easier way to create circle div than using an image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4840736/easier-way-to-create-circle-div-than-using-an-image)

[How to use CSS to surround a number with a circle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4861224/how-to-css-a-number-to-be-surrounded-by-a-circle)

Comment: I didn't know something like css3 pie existed. This does seem like superior way of doing it but im gonna wait a while before accepting this... maybe check out css3 pie a little more.

Comment: pretty revolutionary stuff i gotta say.. feel like hitting my head on a wall for not knowing about this :D