# How to draw circle in html page?

Tags: html, css, geometry, css-shapes

How do you draw a circle using HTML5 and CSS3?

Is it also possible to put text inside?

Comment: Just a circle: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4840736/easier-way-to-create-circle-div-than-using-an-image/4844059#4844059. Circle with text: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4861224/how-to-css-a-number-to-be-surrounded-by-a-circle/4861306#4861306.

Answer (score 216, accepted):

You can't draw a circle per se. But you can make something identical to a circle.

You'd have to create a rectangle with rounded corners (via `border-radius`) that are *one-half the width/height* of the circle you want to make.

```css
    #circle {
      width: 50px;
      height: 50px;
      -webkit-border-radius: 25px;
      -moz-border-radius: 25px;
      border-radius: 25px;
      background: red;
    }
```

```html
<div id="circle"></div>
```

Comment: On second thought, you may want to stick a &nbsp; inside that <div> to make sure it gets displayed. Otherwise, the browser might ignore it.

Comment: I think this answer is wrong as it says you can't draw a circle in HTML5. Canvas is a HTML5 element though and you CAN draw a circle in HTML5 (http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_canvas.asp)

Comment: So basically to turn a div into circle you have to set both of **width** and **height** some **size**, and the border radius the **half** of width.

Comment: use
    -webkit-border-radius: 100%;
    -moz-border-radius: 100%;
    border-radius: 100%;
this way you need only to cusomize width and height to apply your changes in future

Comment: you have to add border to make it visible.

Comment: I found using `border-radius: 50%;` worked well, change the size as desired. For colour you can use `background-color` or `border`.

Comment: i used  **background-color** to make it visible

Comment: lets assume we want to show a tooltip on hover over the circle, now is it possible that we detect hover on the circle region only and not the box area around the circle?

Answer (score 87):

It is quite possible in **HTML 5**. Your options are: [Embedded SVG](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/html5/html5_svg.htm) and [`<canvas>` tag](http://diveintohtml5.info/canvas.html).

To draw circle in embedded SVG:

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="50" fill="red" />
</svg>
```

Circle in `<canvas>`:

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("circlecanvas");
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
context.arc(50, 50, 50, 0, Math.PI * 2, false);
context.fillStyle = "red";
context.fill()
```

```html
<canvas id="circlecanvas" width="100" height="100"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 56):

There are a few unicode circles you could use:

```css
* { font-size: 50px; }
```

```html
&#x25CB;
&#x25CC;
&#x25CD;
&#x25CE;
&#x25CF;
```

More shapes [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_Shapes).

You can overlay text on the circles if you want to:

```css
#container {
    position: relative;
}
#circle {
  font-size: 50px;
  color: #58f;
}
#text {
    z-index: 1;
    position: absolute;
    top: 21px;
    left: 11px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <div id="circle">&#x25CF;</div>
    <div id="text">a</div>
</div>
```

You could also use a custom font (like [this](http://fontawesome.io) one) if you want to have a higher chance of it looking the same on different systems since not all computers/browsers have the same fonts installed.

Answer (score 22):

`border-radius:50%` if you want the circle to adjust to whatever dimensions the container gets (e.g. if the text is variable length)

<del>Don't forget the `-moz-` and `-webkit-` prefixes!</del> (*prefixing* no longer needed)

```css
div{
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  background: lightgreen;
}

.a{
  padding: 50px;
}

.b{
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class='a'></div>
<div class='b'></div>
```

Comment: You have to make sure both width and height are equal, otherwise it will create an oval.

Answer (score 10):

As of 2015, you can make it and center the text with as few as 15 lines of CSS ([Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/81uuLmhy/)):

```css
body {
  background-color: #fff;
}
#circle {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #09f;
  margin: 20px auto;
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  border-radius: 200px;
}
#text {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>circle with text</title>

</head>

<body>
  <div id="circle">
    <div id="text">Text in the circle</div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Without any `-webkit-`s, this works on IE11, Firefox, Chrome and Opera, and it is valid HTML5 (experimental) and CSS3.

Same on MS Edge (2020).

Answer (score 6):

`border-radius: 50%;` will turn all elements into a circle, regardless of size. At least, *as long as the* `height` *and* `width` *of the target are the same, otherwise it will turn into an oval*.

```css
#target{
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: #aaa;
    border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div id="target"></div>
```

**Note**: [browser prefixes are **not** needed anymore for border-radius](https://caniuse.com/#search=border-radius)

---

Alternatively, you can use `clip-path: circle();` to turn an element into a circle as well. Even if the element has a greater `width` than `height` (or the other way around), it will still become a circle, and *not* an oval.

```css
#target{
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: #aaa;
    clip-path: circle();
}
```

```html
<div id="target"></div>
```

**Note**: [clip-path is **not** (yet) supported by all browsers](https://caniuse.com/#search=clip-path)

---

You can place text inside of the circle, simply by writing the text inside of the tags of the target, 
like so:

```
<div>text</div>
```

If you want to *center* text in the circle, you can do the following:

```css
#target{
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: #aaa;
    border-radius: 50%;

    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}

#text{
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="target">
    <div id="text">text</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for mentioning clip-path!

Answer (score 5):

There is not technically a way to draw a circle with HTML (there isn’t a `<circle>` HTML tag), but a circle can be drawn.

The best way to draw one is to add `border-radius: 50%` to a tag such as `div`. Here’s an example:

```
<div style="width: 50px; height: 50px; border-radius: 50%;">You can put text in here.....</div>
```

Answer (score 5):

```css
.circle{
    height: 65px;
    width: 65px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border:1px solid red;
    line-height: 65px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="circle"><span>text</span></div>
```

Answer (score 5):

The followings are my 9 solutions. Feel free to insert text into the divs or svg elements.

1. border-radius
2. clip-path
3. html entity
4. pseudo element
5. radial-gradient
6. svg circle & path
7. canvas arc()
8. img tag
9. pre tag

```js
var c = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
var ctx = c.getContext('2d');
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(50, 50, 50, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
ctx.fillStyle = '#B90136';
ctx.fill();
```

```css
#circle1 {
  background-color: #B90136;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 50px;
}

#circle2 {
  background-color: #B90136;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  clip-path: circle();
}

#circle3 {
  color: #B90136;
  font-size: 100px;
  line-height: 100px;
}

#circle4::before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  background-color: #B90136;
}

#circle5 {
  background-image: radial-gradient(#B90136 70%, transparent 30%);
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<h3>1 border-radius</h3>
<div id="circle1"></div>
<hr/>
<h3>2 clip-path</h3>
<div id="circle2"></div>
<hr/>
<h3>3 html entity</h3>
<div id="circle3">&#11044;</div>
<hr/>
<h3>4 pseudo element</h3>
<div id="circle4"></div>
<hr/>
<h3>5 radial-gradient</h3>
<div id="circle5"></div>
<hr/>
<h3>6 svg circle & path</h3>
<svg width="100" height="100">
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="50" fill="#B90136" />
</svg>
<hr/>
<h3>7 canvas arc()</h3>
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="100" height="100"></canvas>
<hr/>
<h3>8 img tag</h3>
&nbsp; &nbsp; &lt;img src="circle.png" width="100" height="100" /&gt;
<hr/>
<h3>9 pre tag</h3>
<pre style="line-height:8px;">
     +++
    +++++
   +++++++
  +++++++++
 +++++++++++
 +++++++++++
 +++++++++++
  +++++++++
   +++++++
    +++++
     +++
</pre>
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use the border-radius attribute to give it a border-radius equivalent to the element's border-radius.  For example:

```
<div style="border-radius 10px; -moz-border-radius 10px; -webkit-border-radius 10px; width: 20px; height: 20px; background: red; border: solid black 1px;">&nbsp;</div>
```

(The reason for using the -moz and -webkit extensions is to support pre-CSS3-final versions of Gecko and Webkit.)

There are more examples on [this page](http://www.cardeo.ca/2010/how-to-create-circles-with-css3-and-no-images).  As far as inserting text, you can do it but you have to be mindful of the positioning, as most browsers' box padding model still uses the outer square.

Answer (score 3):

You can use border-radius property, or make a div with fixed height and width and a background with png circle.

Answer (score 3):

1. ```css
   h1 {
   border: dashed 2px blue;
     width: 200px;
     height: 200px;
     border-radius: 100px;
     text-align: center;
     line-height: 60px;
     
   }
   ```

   ```html
   <h1> <br>hello world</h1>
   ```

Answer (score 3):

- No width *and* height requirement (specify whatever you prefer)
- No SVG, canvas or Unicode

```css
.circle {
    background: green;
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 1rem;
    aspect-ratio: 1/1;
}
```

```html
<div class="circle"></div>
```

[Browser support](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/aspect-ratio):

- Chrome/Edge 88+
- Firefox 89+

Answer (score 2):

Simply do the following in the script tags:

```html
<!Doctype html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Circle Canvas</title>
</head>
<body>
 <canvas id="myCanvas" width="300" height="150" style="border:1px solid 
#d3d3d3;">
 <body>
  <script>
   var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
   var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
   ctx.beginPath();
   ctx.arc(100, 75, 50, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
   ctx.stroke();
  </script>
    </body>
</body>
</html>
```

And there you go you got your circle.

Comment: Which language is this supposed to be? The OP asked about HTML5 and CSS3.

Comment: This can be done in html using the script tags i think i mentioned in the first line @ClausWilke

Comment: Please provide a complete example then that shows how you use this inside an HTML document. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43648337/4975218) for an example of what a complete example looks like.

Comment: I think that should help what you were not able to understand if you want i can add a pic of the result how the circle looks like. . .

Comment: Not necessay. I put it into a code snippet. It runs when you click the button.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a circle that I used for a CS 1.6 stats website.
A beautiful four colors circle.

```css
#circle {
      border-top: 8px ridge #d11967;
      border-right: 8px ridge #d32997;
      border-bottom: 8px ridge #5246eb;
      border-left: 8px ridge #fc2938;
      border-radius: 50%; width: 440px; height: 440px;
}
```

```html
<div id="circle"></div>
```

Adjust the circle diameter by chaging the width and height.

You can also rotate and skew by using skewY(), skewX() and rotate():

```
  transform: rotate(60deg);
  transform: skewY(-5deg);
  transform: skewX(-15deg);
```

Comment: The blue and pink sections have their shadow on the wrong side, but other than that great 3D effect.

Comment: You can change as needed!

Comment: @HashimAziz this is just an example. You can add a shadow on whichever side you need.
In a circle, there's no wrong side. It depends where you need your object light to be.

Answer (score 1):

```
.at-counter-box {
    border: 2px solid #1ac6ff;
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    border-radius: 100px;
    font-family: 'Oswald Sans', sans-serif;
    color:#000;
}
.at-counter-box-content {
    position: relative;
}
.at-counter-content span {
    font-size: 40px;
    font-weight: bold ;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    top: 55px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
   <head>
       <style>

       #circle{
       width:200px;
       height:200px;
       border-radius:100px;
       background-color:red;
       }
       </style>
   </head>

    <body>
       <div id="circle"></div>
   </body>
```

simple and novice :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="at-counter-box-content">

  <div class="at-counter-content">

      <span>40%</span>

  </div><!--at-counter-content-->

</div><!--at-counter-box-content-->
```

Comment: Although this code may answer the question, providing
additional context regarding _why_ and/or _how_ it answers
the question would significantly improve its long-term
value.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using sass to write your CSS you can do:

```
@mixin draw_circle($radius){
  width: $radius*2;
  height: $radius*2;
  -webkit-border-radius: $radius;
  -moz-border-radius: $radius;
  border-radius: $radius;
}

.my-circle {
  @include draw_circle(25px);
  background-color: red;
}
```

Which outputs:

```
.my-circle {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 25px;
  -moz-border-radius: 25px;
  border-radius: 25px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

Try it here: https://www.sassmeister.com/