# how to do a circular layout with CSS

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a layout with these circular layers in each section of the site, but am having difficulty as it is not a very easy task, can someone give me a light?

[image: photoshop psd of the future website]

Comment: What specifically is the problem? Do you not know how to make the circles? You can use the [`border-radius`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-radius) property of CSS to make corners, if that's what you're asking.

Comment: Use [`border-radius`](http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/b/border-radius/) in combination with `relative` positioning

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to draw circle in html page?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6921792/how-to-draw-circle-in-html-page)

Comment: no, not a possible duplicate, this is different

Comment: and i'm talking not about the menu, but about the body...see the circular body

Answer (score 1):

You have a few choices:

- using css `border-radius` with a radius of 100% on a square element
- Or just create a circular transparent .png and use it as the background of a
  `<div>`.

border-radius example http://jsfiddle.net/VKf3T/4/

Comment: this layout must be responsive, and i have problems doing this.

Comment: That is not implied by your question. If you want good answers, ask the right question.

Comment: this can still be responsive - you'd need to either use a responsive framework, bootstrap and susy are some examples and you'd need to essentially adjust the sizes of the circles according to the width of the monitor/device. If your quesitons are on how to make the circular layout responsive, I'd suggest making a new question (after looking that up on the forum - there are quite a lot of questions discussing responsive design on this site)

Answer (score 1):

[This is pretty trivial actually](http://jsfiddle.net/vXxsn/).

Use a block level element with identical fixed height and width, and apply `border-radius:50%` to make it completely circular.

Comment: i'm talking about the layout at sections below the menu

Comment: Perhaps you should write a better question than a one liner then if we're to guess what the question actually is.