# Make a pure css circle with gradients and without gradients

Tags: css

I failed to create a circle with below code. Can you explain how CSS circles work?

```
.circle {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background: #4679BD;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to draw circle in html page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6921792/how-to-draw-circle-in-html-page)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Without gradients**

```
.circle {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    -moz-border-radius: 50%; 
    -webkit-border-radius: 50%; 
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: #4679BD;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In CSS you can use border-radius 
You can set the value to 50% for pure circle or you can set the value in px for having a shape with a rounded corners

Your code should be like:

```
.circle {
        width: 200px;
        height: 200px;
        border-radius: 50%;
    }
```