# How Do i Center Text In CSS?

Tags: html, css, geometry

I have the following code.

```css
.circle
{
width:251px;
height:251px;
border-radius:50%;
font-size:16px;
color:#fff;
line-height:50px;
text-align:center;
background:#000;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<body>
<div class="circle">Hello Guys! Please help Me...</div>
</body>
```

[jsFiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/35jxk7td/4/)

What I want to do is center the text but I don't know how to do that.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6921792/how-to-draw-circle-in-html-page/31708125#31708125

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/35jxk7td/5/

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/b6335umv/1/
line-height is what you need.

```
.circle
{
width:251px;
height:251px;
border-radius:50%;
font-size:16px;
color:#fff;
text-align:center;
background:#000;
line-height: 251px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Line height is a good solution for this. The key being (when the containing element has a defined height) that line-height and the containing elements height are the same. 
In your case

```
.circle {
  width:251px;
  height:251px;
  border-radius:50%;
  font-size:16px;
  color:#fff;
  line-height:251px;
  text-align:center;
  background:#000;
}
```

However in responsive cases where the elements are more fluid and the height isn't explicitly defined, it's usually better to use use line-height without units. [This article](http://meyerweb.com/eric/thoughts/2006/02/08/unitless-line-heights/) has a pretty good explanation of the details about why.

Comment: I liked how you were specific. I should keep this in mind. Thanks!