# Make modal in circle shape

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I want to create a modal in circle shape instead of the regular rectangle with rounded corners. So it should look something like just a round with the `modal-body` in middle, no `modal-header` and no `modal-footer`.

This is with modal to make sure how it works, instead of regular html circle.

I just want it to look like this.

[image]

Comment: border-radius: 100% with equal width and height should do it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to draw circle in html page?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6921792/how-to-draw-circle-in-html-page)

Comment: @jmattheis No it is about modals! Not circle in html page

Comment: @danimal can u show an example with modals?

Comment: @Sibidharan a model is just a html tag (with content) which you can style

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll need to experiment with the location of the content within the modal, but here's a working example I've just made using `border-radius`: https://jsfiddle.net/2ahhsa4a/1/

```
.modal-content {
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 600px;
    height: 600px;
    border: 15px solid #000;
}
```

You'll notice I've used fixed `width` / `height` for the modal, this is to ensure it is a perfect circle when combined with `border-radius` for this example.

Comment: It looks satisfying. I will mark as correct after implementing out :)

Comment: @Sibidharan No problem, happy to help. You'll need to tweak it of course but it gives you a base to build on.

Comment: Sure, I got it.. I can tweak it to fit the text as I like :)

Comment: @Sibidharan Remember to mark an answer as correct if it helps you out - it may help others in the future :-)

Comment: It helped me! It perfectly worked after doing few alignment tweaks!! 

Answer (score 1):

HTML

```
      <div class="modal-body rounded">
        <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
      </div>
```

CSS

```
.rounded {border-radius: 100%; width: 500px; height: 500px;}
```