# how to make the circular pointer at the video progress bar, in css and Html?

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, nuxt.js

I'm a junior frontend developer and I am building a video player and I cannot create that circular pointer at the end of the video progress bar. I've tried to create a span and div with dimensions but it doesn't display anything in the browser.
I'm using vue and Nuxt 3 Js.

This is the sample of my code:

```html
<div class="progress-bar" @click="skipVideo">
    <div :style="{ width: progressPercentage() + '%' }" class="current-bar"></div>
</div>
```

[image]

I've tried to create a span and div with dimensions but it doesn't display anything in the browser.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to draw circle in html page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6921792/how-to-draw-circle-in-html-page)

Answer (score 0):

At the moment, you can't style a video player directly with css. The hack is to create your own video player with html buttons to be able to create what you want.

If you can, try not to mess up with any native player, that way you won't have to recreate all the mechanics of a real video player.

If you really need to recreate a player, I invite you to follow a tutorial on internet, like this one https://blog.logrocket.com/creating-customizing-html5-video-player-css.

Another possibility is to add a npm package to your project that can take care of the design of the video player.