# Create divs 100% round

Tags: html, css, canvas

I have tried unsuccessfully to create divs 100% but have not gotten round. Does anyone know how to do? I'm using border-radius command and setting the various values ​​mesmacom px and percentage but so far, nothing = / as you do this, create divs 100% round?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Easier way to create circle div than using an image?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4840736/easier-way-to-create-circle-div-than-using-an-image)

Answer (score 3):

Actually, this is a better approach:

```
.round {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

Notice the use of a percentage as the border-radius. This way, you can just change the height/width and get bigger/smaller circles.

Answer (score 0):

You just make the `border-radius` half of the width and height.

```
div { height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    border-radius: 50px;
}
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/j7vD7/