# How to display images based on their distance to the center image?

Tags: php, css

[image]

This example is what I want. I am wondering is that possible to display img1, img2 and img3 based on their distance to the center image?(Say I know the distance between img1 and center is 2, img2 to center is 3, img3 to center is 1)

Comment: You are talking about a circle path. 360 different positions.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4840736/easier-way-to-create-circle-div-than-using-an-image

This can be a starting step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to use JavaScript to write inline CSS for you. The D3.js library is wonderful for building these type of diagrams.

Here is a similar example from the D3.js website:
http://bl.ocks.org/couchand/6420534

More examples here:
https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Gallery

Answer (score 0):

I think it is possible. Know the center image position and make it absolute. let the other image distances be relative to it.

Comment: But refer to the image given, there are lines linked to the center.I think Canvas is required.