# How to circle around text in a HTML document?

Tags: html, css

I'd like to put

1. a circle or
2. a broken circle (like if I were to draw a circle freehand without completely closing it) or
3. a square, or
4. brackets

i.e.

```
       non-bracketed text. non-bracketed 
       text. non-bracketed text. non-
    +- bracketed text. Bracketed text    -+
    |  that can span several lines and    |
    +- more.  non-bracketed text.  non-  -+
       bracketed text. non-bracketed
       text.
```

I saw this: [Easier way to create circle div than using an image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4840736/easier-way-to-create-circle-div-than-using-an-image) but text is in the top left hand corner if I were to draw a circle around it, which isn't what I want.

I saw this: [css: how to draw circle with text in middle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16615403/css-how-to-draw-circle-with-text-in-middle) but text is centred and I want the circle to go around the text, not move the text to be within the circle.

---

#### CLARIFICATION

The text is *already* aligned and I **do not** want it to be realigned so that the circle will go around it.  The circle **must** move to compensate for the text, **NOT** the other way around.

Also, I need to be able to switch between the 4 different circles fairly easily.  Preferable by just changing the class of the tag.

Here is a sample as to what I'm looking for:

[image: sample]

#### Question:

Can I please get people to vote this open so it can get this post off hold?  This is quite specific and I would challenge anyone to say why it is not.

#### Answer:

With the help of dcclassics, asking of more questions and doing more searching, I've got a solution.

http://jsfiddle.net/adrianh/4SVHH/7/

```
function getCanvas(i, left, top, width, height)
{
    var canvas;
    var circles = document.getElementById("circles");
    if (typeof circles.childNodes[i] != 'undefined')
    {
        canvas = circles.childNodes[i];
        canvas.width=width;
        canvas.height=height;
        canvas.style.left=left+"px";
        canvas.style.top=top+"px";
    }
    else
    {
        canvas = "<canvas "+
        "width='"+width+"' "+
        "height='"+height+"' "+
        "style='"+
            "position:absolute;"+
            "z-index:0;"+
            "left:"+left+"px;"+
            "top:"+top+"px;"+
            "pointer-events:none;"+
            //"border:1px solid;"+
        "' />";
        circles.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', canvas);
    }
    return circles.childNodes[i];
}

function circleRect(i, rect)
{
    var diameter = Math.sqrt(rect.width*rect.width+rect.height*rect.height);
    var cx = (rect.right + rect.left)/2;
    var cy = (rect.top + rect.bottom)/2;
    var left = Math.floor(cx - diameter/2);
    var top  = Math.floor(cy - diameter/2);
    diameter = Math.floor(diameter);
    var canvas = getCanvas(i, left-1, top-1, diameter+2, diameter+2);
    var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(diameter/2+1,diameter/2+1,diameter/2,0,2*Math.PI);
    ctx.lineWidth=2;
    ctx.strokeStyle = "red";
    ctx.stroke();
}

function rectRect(i, rect)
{
    var canvas = getCanvas(i, rect.left-1, rect.top-1, rect.width+2, rect.height+2);
    var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(1, 1);
    ctx.lineTo(rect.width+1, 1);
    ctx.lineTo(rect.width+1, rect.height+1);
    ctx.lineTo(1, rect.height+1);
    ctx.lineTo(1, 1);
    ctx.strokeStyle = "red";
    ctx.lineWidth=2;
    ctx.stroke();
}

function drawCircles()
{
    $(".circled").each(function(i, obj) {
        var rect = obj.getBoundingClientRect();
        if (/\brect\b/.test(obj.className))
        {
            rectRect(i, rect);
        }
        else
        {
            circleRect(i, rect);
        }
    });
}
document.body.insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', '<div id="circles"></div>');
drawCircles();

window.onresize=drawCircles;
```

The solution presented shows only a circle and a rectangle, but this can be modified to be used for any type of circling method that I asked for.  This doesn't use a svg file, but uses a canvas instead.  This may limit it to more recent browsers, but that isn't a problem for me.

Comment: Is there a question here?

Comment: Use an image. Scale it if necessary.

Comment: @j08691 Yes, how would I circle around text in an HTML document.

Comment: @Ruud, using CSS or an image (which I guess you mean by using it as a background?) this wouldn't work if this were a circle/oval.  I don't see how I would get it to work if the text is to remain within the circle.  Could you expand please?

Comment: "I want the circle to go around the text", If you draw a circle around text which is aligned horizontally, obviously the text will be in the middle of the circle. So actually you want the text to be aligned in a circular manner, right..?

Comment: @TJ I don't want the text to be moved, I want the circle to be around the already aligned text.

Comment: It's easy to put brackets around text...  am I missing something there?

Comment: Yes, I know that it is easy to put brackets around the text, but this is to grab attention and different visual mechanisms are to be used in different instances.  It is a requirement that I was given.

Comment: How is this too broad?  It is very specific.  I'm not sure what is meant by "too broad".

Comment: You can use an svg as background-image of your text, and add the property background-size:cover (or the width and height of the text container). For the brackets you can use css property 'content' used with selectors :before and :after

Comment: @keypaul, can you post that as an answer with a sample?

Comment: The question is too broad because you want someone to code up the entire solution for you.  Do some work, get stuck (or not!) and then we can help you work out the kinks.  But, at first glance, keypaul's `svg` suggestion is probably the most flexible.  Ruud's image suggestion is the easiest.  A css solution is likely to be limited, I don't know how you'd do a broken circle that way at all, and brackets would be kind of hacky.

Comment: @Jason, I've pretty much gotten as far as dcclacics had.  Although I know some html and css, this is not my forte.  I'm a C++ developer. Not only that, but too broad according to the SO closed questions page states `if your question could be answered by an entire book, or has many valid answers, it's probably too broad for our format`.  This is definitely not the case.  To mark it as such is an abuse of the system.

Comment: It has many valid answers, by the nature that there are multiple potential solutions, there are multiple ways to accomplish those solutions, and you have posted none of your own code to guide us to a particular one.

It's an abuse of the system to use us to get you up to speed on things that are not your forte without your posting even a line of code.  I sympathize with your situation, but I think you've gotten enough here to do some more work on your own down your chosen path, and come back (with code!) if you get stuck again.  This is the way SO works.

Comment: @Jason, I only saw the background image answer.  However, I didn't really see any other answer.  Even looking in to this further, I only found one other potential solution, which I have posted.  Do you have any other potential solutions you can think of?

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/V9Gn5/2/) is a jsFiddle of a circle around text.

```
<div class="circle">Circle</div>

.circle {
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    text-align: center;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/V9Gn5/ shows an elipse, not a circle, around some text, but without moving the text.

Edit: Here's as close as I could get right now, if someone else would like to play around with it.  http://jsfiddle.net/V9Gn5/19/

Comment: Now change `text-align` to `left` and `vertical-align` to `top` and see what you get.  That is what I don't want, which is what I said in the 3rd paragraph.

Comment: @Adrian, so let's say the text is at the exact upper left corner of your document.  How would you expect the circle to look?

Comment: @andi With the text bounding box inscribed within the circle.

Comment: but then the circle wouldn't even fit on the page - you would expect the circle to be chopped off at the top left?

Comment: I dont think anyone understands really what you're looking for here.

Comment: Here a fiddle with some example http://jsfiddle.net/keypaul/g3YjT/28/  Maybe post an image or other so we can understand better what do you expect

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/V9Gn5/16/  Something like this is really the only other thing I could recommend.  Unless you show us an image of your desired outcome.

Comment: Okay, that helps a lot.  Give me a few minutes to mock something up.

Comment: Hmmm, I'd rather that (and the specs require that) the bounding box is inscribed within the circle (ellipse), even when spanning lines.  As you can see [here](http://jsfiddle.net/cLfZV/), it is not.  You may have to narrow your browser to see it span a line.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/V9Gn5/19/ this is as close as I can get right now if someone wants to play with it.

Comment: Svg i think works for you, cause you can use it as image, also scaling, stretching without loose quality. You can use it as background of your text ( like the fiddle in my previous comment)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/keypaul/RCkQ3/32/ here little fiddle of what i mean

Comment: Have you solved your problem?