# how to create these glyphicons with bootstrap in React?

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-4, react-bootstrap

the glyphicons of facebook, twitter, instagram and youtube in a react project with bootstrap with circles around them as shown in the image.

[image: Here is the image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Easier way to create circle div than using an image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4840736/easier-way-to-create-circle-div-than-using-an-image)

Answer (score 0):

First you will need a font-icon that has those icons, I use [ico-moon](https://icomoon.io/) because you can then select only those 5 icons you need unlike fontawesome or other icon libraries. or you can use svg.

in case u choose to go with a font-icon, All u have to do is add it like any other font-face in ur global style, and then u can use like this , Icon is just a simple React Component with icon style.